# How do I render data from two inputs into two different elements, using React and Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-props

I am creating a Todo list using React and Fireabase. Originally I managed to create a todo via an input and have it render as a list, but then I realised I would like to have a heading for each todo. So I created another hook to capture the input for the heading, added it to the addTodo function then created another input element below for it. I then went to the component where it renders and tried to use props. Unfortunately though, only the first input renders in the list. How can I get the second element to also render in the list? I added a console.log and they are both showing up (in the console).

This is the file, in case it helps.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import classes from "./addlink.module.css";


import firebase from "firebase/app";
import initFirebase from "../../config";
import "firebase/firestore";

import Todo from "../Todo/Todo";

import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

initFirebase();
const db = firebase.firestore();

function AddLink(props) {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [inputLinks, setInputLinks] = useState("");
  const [inputHeaders, setInputHeaders] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("links")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        setTodos(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            todo: doc.data().todo,
          }))
        );
      });
  }, []);

  const addTodo = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    db.collection("links").add({
      id: uuidv4(),
      todo: inputLinks,
      title: inputHeaders,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
    console.log(inputLinks);
    console.log(inputHeaders);
    setInputLinks("");
    setInputHeaders("");
  };

  /

  return (
    <div className={classes.addlink}>
      <form>
        <div className={classes.adminlink}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={inputLinks}
            onChange={(event) => setInputLinks(event.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            value={inputHeaders}
            onChange={(event) => setInputHeaders(event.target.value)}
          />
          <button
            className={classes.adminbutton}
            type="submit"
            onClick={addTodo}
          >
            Add new link
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <Todo todo={todo} title={todo.title} key={todo.id} />
      ))}
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddLink;
```

And the Todo.js

```
import React from "react";
import { AiOutlinePicture } from "react-icons/ai";
import { AiOutlineStar } from "react-icons/ai";
import { GoGraph } from "react-icons/go";
import DeleteForeverIcon from "@material-ui/icons/DeleteForever";

import classes from "./todo.module.css";

import firebase from "firebase/app";
import initFirebase from "../../config";
import "firebase/firestore";

initFirebase();
const db = firebase.firestore();

function Todo(props) {
  const deleteHandler = (event) => {
    db.collection("links").doc(props.todo.id).delete();
  };

  return (
    <li className={classes.adminsection}>
      <div className={classes.linkCards}>
        <h3>{props.todo.title}</h3>
        <p>{props.todo.todo}</p>
        <div>
          <AiOutlinePicture />
          <AiOutlineStar />
          <GoGraph />
          <DeleteForeverIcon onClick={deleteHandler} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
}

export default Todo;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to give the `Todo` component a unique ID:

```js
<Todo id={todo.id} todo={todo} title={todo.title} key={todo.id} />
```

When maping multiple elements in react they should all have an unique `id`.

Also in this part remove the `todo`:

```js
 setTodos(
  snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
   id: doc.id,
   todo: doc.data().todo, //here
  }))
 );
```

it should be like this:

```js
 setTodos(
  snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
    id: doc.id,
    todo: doc.data(),
  }))
 );
```

Othervise you would have only the `todo` value and not the `data` as you expect it in the other parts of your code.

Comment: Hi Tarik. When I remove the .todo after the doc.data() I get a runtime error